# my index starts from the second row but i need it on the first

Tags: python, pandas

```
my CSV file looks like this

Edan Daniele;12.61;5.00;9.22;1.50;60.39;16.43;21.60;2.60;35.81;5.25.72
Lehi Poghos;13.04;4.53;7.79;1.55;64.72;18.74;24.20;2.40;28.20;6.50.76
Coos Kwesi;13.75;4.84;10.12;1.50;68.44;19.18;30.85;2.80;33.88;6.22.75
Severi Eileifr;13.43;4.35;8.64;1.50;66.06;19.05;24.89;2.20;33.48;6.51.01

and my code
 
from datetime import time
from os import sep
import pandas as pd
df  =   pd.read_csv("Decathlon.csv",sep=";")
print (df)
```

the terminal prompts me that Lehi is the first on the index while it should be edan

```
     Edan Daniele  12.61  5.00   9.22  1.50  60.39  16.43  21.60  2.60  35.81  5.25.72
0     Lehi Poghos  13.04  4.53   7.79  1.55  64.72  18.74  24.20   2.4  28.20  6.50.76
1      Coos Kwesi  13.75  4.84  10.12  1.50  68.44  19.18  30.85   2.8  33.88  6.22.75
2  Severi Eileifr  13.43  4.35   8.64  1.50  66.06  19.05  24.89   2.2  33.48  6.51.01
```

Comment: Set the header as None : -> ``pd.read_csv("Decathlon.csv",sep=";", header=None)``

Comment: `from datetime import time
from os import sep
import pandas as pd
df  =   pd.read_csv("Decathlon.csv",sep=";")
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df.columns  =   ["Name","100 m","Long jump","Shot put","High jump","400 m","110 m hurdles","Discus throw","Pole vault","Javelin throw","1500 m"]
print (df)
df['100m score'] =  round(25.4347*((18-df["100 m"])**1.81))
df["Long jump score"]   =   0.14354*(((df["Long jump"]-220)*-1)**1.4)
df["shot put score"]   =  51.39*((df["Shot put"]-1.5)**1.05)
df["high jump score"]   =   0.8465*(((df["High jump"]-75)*-1)**1.42)this is how it looks now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
df  =   pd.read_csv("Decathlon.csv",sep=";",header=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it reads the first line as columns now if you try to print columns

```
for col in df.columns:
    print(col)
```

you will get this output

```
Edan Daniele,12.61,5.00,9.22,1.50,60.39,16.43,21.60,2.60,35.81,5.25.72
```

you can try

```
df  =   pd.read_csv("Book1.csv", header=None)
```

but then you will get columns as `0,1,2,3,4` which can be a bit difficult to work with since you won't remember what  column 3 or 5  is for

what I suggest you do is to add columns to your CSV so it looks like this
you can give names to values like Price.. depending on what are these values

```
Name;Value1;Value2;Value3;Value4;Value5;Value6;Value7;Value8;Value9;Value10

Edan Daniele;12.61;5.00;9.22;1.50;60.39;16.43;21.60;2.60;35.81;5.25.72
Lehi Poghos;13.04;4.53;7.79;1.55;64.72;18.74;24.20;2.40;28.20;6.50.76
Coos Kwesi;13.75;4.84;10.12;1.50;68.44;19.18;30.85;2.80;33.88;6.22.75
Severi Eileifr;13.43;4.35;8.64;1.50;66.06;19.05;24.89;2.20;33.48;6.51.01
```

now if you try

```
df  =   pd.read_csv("Decathlon.csv",sep=";")
```

your output would be like this

```
          Name   Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 Value5 Value6 Value7 Value8 Value9 Value10
0    Edan Daniele  12.61  5.00   9.22  1.50  60.39  16.43  21.60  2.60  35.81  5.25.72
1     Lehi Poghos  13.04  4.53   7.79  1.55  64.72  18.74  24.20   2.4  28.20  6.50.76
2      Coos Kwesi  13.75  4.84  10.12  1.50  68.44  19.18  30.85   2.8  33.88  6.22.75
3  Severi Eileifr  13.43  4.35   8.64  1.50  66.06  19.05  24.89   2.2  33.48  6.51.01
```